# How to upload a file first then submit to insertQuestion.php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a script where it uploads a file which is known as upload_file.php. The problem is though that I already have a form action where the page (QandATable.php) submits to (insertQuestion.php). So what I want to know is how can I post to the upload_php in the background so when user submits the form, it navigates the user to the insertQuestion.php page but it does post file locations to the uplodad_file.php page in the background?

Below is the form action and submit button:

```
<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" /></p>

</form>
```

UPDATE:

Will the AJAX below works if I want to post the whole form to both createSession.php and upload_files.php in the background?

```
         function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("createSession.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
    $.post("upload_files.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });  
    alert("Your Details for this Session has been submitted"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean: "How to upload a file first then submit to insertQuestion.php?"

Comment: @sergzach Yes that is what I mean. When a user clicks on a submit button, it will post files to upload_files.php for uploading but it does not navigate the user to that page, but after files are uploaded then navigate user to insertQuestions.php

Comment: the insertQuestion.php is a php script where all the INSERT VALUES occur in the database, am I able to include the script from the upload_files.php into the insertQuestions.php and then use AJAX to call upon insertQuestion.php, In other words insertQuestion contains both the script for mysql and uploading files?

Comment: Use AJAX. it'll definitely do the job

Comment: Could the AJAX above work to perform background posts to both createSession.php and upload_file.php?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand, you can use `header()`

#### QandATable.php

```
<form action='upload.php' ...>
// you form details
</form>
```

#### upload.php

```
ob_start();
 // do uploads 
header('Location:insertQuestion.php');
exit();
```